# How to make column go reversibly blank with custom validation and conditional format rules

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I was able to use scripts editor to make some conditional formatting. Would like the option of covering up the answer column, column B reversibly. Would love some help with a script or how to do this. Just learning how to program.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kBTrLIxMBRcKB-Y2gJxPP_-_zihOc4xFTFrgDktZp-M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] While including a link to an external resource might be helpful, questions on this site should be self contained and specific. What do you mean by "Would like the option of covering up the answer column, column B reversibly"? Have you already tried something? Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by conditionally formatting column B, based on the values ​​in column D

See if [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytFWahz3NmOCqA5SvbPG4SVn0li3GvNbmehxQXKmOTM/edit?usp=sharing) might suit you